# Unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is not compact

Tags: general-topology

> Question:
>
> Prove that the open unit ball $B_{1}\left ( \vec{0} \right )$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is not compact.

I have the definition of "compact" but I am unable to start on this question.
Taking a fresh look at my notes, I suspect this has to do with the Heine-Borel theorem.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not closed and $\Bbb R^n$ is $T2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no finite subcover of $\{\,B_{1-\frac1n}(\vec0)\mid n\in\Bbb N\,\}$

Comment: I too was trying to come up with some infinite covering not having a finite subcovering, but my tries were much more fancy. The simplicity of your covering is beautiful (+1). And it's actually extremely easy to generalize it to any open bounded subset, say $\Omega$, by picking the familiy of sets :
$$A_n:=\{x\in \Omega\mid d(x,\partial \Omega)>1/n\}$$

Comment: Giving you an upvote for the simplicity.

Comment: @Mathematicing I was wondering if $\{\,B_r(\vec0)\mid 0<r<1\,\}$ would be simpler ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Allow me to try that tomorrow. This could be an alternate demonstration of a proof.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically an automatic consequence of the Heine Borel theorem (which as stated in your question, you already have):

> Theorem: a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

Question: Is your set closed?

Comment: I started with R^{1} space. Then showed that the ball centered at a point x=0 in R^{1} is an open space; or not a closed space.
This generalises to R^{n}. And the result follows from the contrapositivity of the HB theorem.

Comment: @Mathematicing Open does not immediately imply not closed.

Comment: I have $B_{1}\left ( \vec{0} \right )=
 \left ( -\epsilon ,+\epsilon  \right ) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ which is not closed.
I misused my language in the earlier comment.